# »Es geht um« + Infinitiv

Tags: verb, infinitive

Neulich wollte ich auf einen Kommentar auf Facebook antworten. Da hab ich geschrieben:

> Es geht nicht um die Farbe der Regierung sondern um Mauern zu errichten.

Aber der Satz hört sich ein bisschen komisch an, finde ich. Sagt man eigentlich »Es geht um ... zu« + Infinitiv?
Was würdet Ihr sonst an der Stelle sagen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Es geht nicht um die Farbe der Regierung, sondern **darum**, Mauern zu errichten.

Es geht nicht um *(Akkusativ-Objekt)*, sondern um *(Akkusativ-Objekt)*.

*die Farbe der Regierung* ist gültig als Objekt.

*Mauern zu errichten* ist aber nur ein Infinitiv und muss angepasst werden.

Tolar macht in seiner Antwort daraus *das Errichten von Mauern*, also wird der Infinitiv substantiviert. In anderen Sätzen böten sich auch noch andere Formen der Substantivierung an - *Mauererrichtung* würde hier jedoch seltsam klingen.

*darum,..* erzeugt einen Verweis auf die Tätigkeit, die dann durch den Infinitiv beschrieben wird (und als Objekt herhalten kann).

Answer (score 4):

Dein Gefühl hat dich nicht getrogen.

*EDIT: Falsche Erklärung entfernt, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.*

Eine Option, bei der die Konstruktion beibehalten wird, wäre eine Umstellung des Satzes zu:

> Es geht nicht um die Farbe der Regierung, sondern um **das Errichten** von Mauern.

Die Antwort von Chieron ist ebenfalls eine korrekte Alternative.

Comment: Danke Euch für die Antworten. "Das Errichten von Mauern" ist eigentlich ganz logisch, ich weiß nicht, warum mir die Konstruktion nicht eingefallen ist.